# Estimate of volume of a ball on the boundary of Riemannian manifold

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, isoperimetric-problems

Let $M^n$ be a smooth compact Riemannian manifold with **geodesically locally convex boundary** and sectional curvature at least $-1$. Let $x\in M$ and $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$.

> Does there exist a constant $C_n$ depending on the dimension $n$ only such that 
>   $$vol_{n-1}(B(x,\varepsilon)\cap \partial M)<C_n\varepsilon^{n-1}$$
>   where $B(x,\varepsilon)$ denotes the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x$?

**Remark.** 
A weaker statement would be sufficient for me:
there exists a function $\tau_n(\varepsilon)$ which converges to 0 when $\varepsilon \to 0$ such that 
$$vol_{n-1}(B(x,\varepsilon)\cap \partial M)<\tau_n(\varepsilon).$$